# finding out whether a graphics object has been touched kivy

Tags: android, python, user-interface, kivy

When I touch down on `MyPaintWidget` an ellipse is created in its `canvas`. 
But I also want to detect when the user touches on the already drawn ellipse so that I can execute other instructions instead of drawing an ellipse again.
I have seen that `self.collide_point` only works with `Widget`s.

Is there an alternative solution?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1,1,0)
            d=30
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the ellipses' centres and radii in a `ListProperty` of `MyPaintWidget`. In `on_touch_down` you can check whether you collide with any of the ellipses and either draw another one or do something else. In the example below, I've added a second radius to show the general solution.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    ellipses = ListProperty()
    def touch_hits_ellipse(self, touch):
        return [ind for ind, e in enumerate(self.ellipses) if (touch.x - e[0] )**2.0/(e[2])**2.0 + (touch.y - e[1])**2/(e[3])**2 <= 1]

    def on_touch_down(self,touch):
        hit_ellipse = self.touch_hits_ellipse(touch)
        if len(hit_ellipse) == 0:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(1,1,0)
                d=30
                d2=40
                Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2,touch.y-d2/2),size=(d, d2))
            self.ellipses.append((touch.x, touch.y, d/2.0, d2/2))
        else:
            print "We hit ellipse(s) {}".format(hit_ellipse)

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyPaintWidget()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```